# Jackson polymorphic objects serialize/deserialize - child classes field is not populated

Tags: json, spring, jackson, polymorphism

I have polymorphic class hierarchy that need to be sent/retrieved to/from REST Api.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = 
       JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public class Property implements IProperty, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
```

And for example one of it's children:

```
public class PropertyEnum extends Property {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String value;
   private Collection<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
```

When sending Property[] arrays to rest resource or getting them back, I have the value field from PropertyEnum empty and not populated!
The values field in other hand is populated.
name is populated for sure because it's on parent class.

I tried as well:

```
//@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include =JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
property = "name")
@JsonSubTypes(value = { 
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PropertyEnum.class, name = "enum")
})

@JsonTypeName("enum")
public class PropertyEnum extends Property {
```

(Despite that requires maintaining code all the time when adding new types!)

one more try:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
property="objectType")
@JsonSubTypes({

    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=PropertyEnum.class)
})
public class Property implements IProperty, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;

protected Property(){}
```

...

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
property="objectType")
public class PropertyEnum extends Property {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String value;
    private Collection<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();

    protected PropertyEnum(){}
```

But I have a strange behavior... one for child fields is populated (values), and the other (value) is not?
I have setter/getter for both!

Any idea?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't figure why one field isn't populated and others are, but I solved it by adding this annotation @JsonProperty to the problematic field.

My solution:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
 property = "@class")
public class Property implements IProperty, Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String name;

   protected Property(){}
```

...

```
public class PropertyEnum extends Property {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @JsonProperty
   private String value;

   private Collection<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();

   protected PropertyEnum(){}
```